# Moving this action that works in the show view into the index view (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is how the user votes the current post that it is showing:

**controllers/votes_controller.rb:**

```
class VotesController < ApplicationController
  def vote_up
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])

    if @post.votes.exists?(:user_id => current_user.id)
      @notice = 'You already voted'
    else
      @vote = @post.votes.create(:user_id => current_user.id, :polarity => 1)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
```

This updates the total number of votes with Ajax:

**vote_up.js.erb:**

```
<% unless @notice.blank? %>
  alert("<%= @notice %>");
<% end %>

<% unless @vote.blank? %>
  $('.post-<%=@post.id%> span.vote-count').html('<%= @post.votes.count %>');
  $('.post-<%=@post.id%> div.voted-user').html('<% @post.votes.each do |vote| %><%= link_to vote.user.username, vote.user %><% end %>');
<% end %>
```

This is the voting link in the show view:

**views/posts/show.html.erb:**

```
<%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_up_path(@post), :remote => true, :class => "vote-up" %><br />
```

and the routing for the action:

**routes.rb:**

```
get 'votes/:id/vote_up' => 'votes#vote_up', as: 'vote_up'
```

This is how all the posts are displayed in the index view:

**views/posts/index.html.erb:**

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h2>Title: <%= post.title %></h2>
    <p>Author: <%= post.user.username %></p>
    <p>Created At: <%= post.created_at %></p>
    <p>Content: <%= post.content %></p>
    <p>Votes: <%= post.total_votes %></p>
    <p>Comments: <%= post.comments_count %></p>
    <ul>
      <li><%= link_to 'Show', post %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></li>
    </ul>
    <br />
  <% end %>
```

I would like to add the voting link in the `index.html.erb` view for each post or find a way of triggering the `vote_up` action for each post in the index view. Any suggestions to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I must be totally missing the point here but why can't you just do the following within the block displaying each post?

```
<%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_up_path(post), :remote => true, :class => "vote-up" %>
```

Note that i'm using `post` not `@post`.

Comment: In addition to that I guess you'll need to update the ID of your Total votes count element to contain the ID of the post so that your JS knows which <p> tag to update

Comment: No you were not missing the point. Maybe my head wasn't clear because of playing with Rails conterminously for 3 days. Thanks!